# Search icon in Toolbar is not restored on orientation change if searching

Tags: android, search, toolbar, screen-orientation

I have a search coupled to a Toolbar through the options menu. When I click the icon, the searchview is expanded, the current view on the display is hidden (View.GONE) and a RecyclerView for the search is exposed (View.VISIBLE). I start typing in the search bar and the elements in the RecyclerView are properly filtered. Now I rotate the screen. I saved a flag `searchActive` that I was searching and the current text in the search bar. On restore, I do the following to restore the state:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "CPA: onPrepareOptionsMenu called");
    if(searchActive)
    {
        searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
        searchView.setQuery(saved_search_text, true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It works fine. The RecyclerView is restored showing a properly filtered list. However, when I click on something, I get the item I want, collapse the search bar using the following:

```
        toolbar.setTitle(CpaPatient.currentPatient.getGivenName());
        toolbar.collapseActionView();
```

The Toolbar is restored and the RecyclerView hidden as is supposed to happen BUT the search icon is missing and I cannot do another search. I need to do one more screen rotation to restore it. Then I can do a search. What step am I missing in the restoration that the icon is missing? I believe it must be associated with the user action to click on the search icon which I am not sure how to simulate but I am not sure. Any ideas? Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I do not like. If someone can find a better one I'd like it. Apparently, restoring the search state in onPrepareOptionsMenu() is still too early, though that is the last callback I will get from the Activity as it restores. So what I did was add a delay

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "CPA: onPrepareOptionsMenu called");
    if(searchActive)
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
                searchView.setQuery(saved_search_text, true);
            }

        }, 200);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I guess the 200 millisecond wait before I programmatically expand the search bar populate its contents allows the Toolbar to be fully restored before my simulated user click is done.

I think this is a pathetic solution. Ideally I should have some indication from the system as when it is fully operational and can invoke such actions.

Comment: Could you find a better solution for this? I came up with the same "solution" which works sometimes, but not always. That definitely can't be the "real" solution...

Comment: I wish I had but I have not. I continue to use the above broken approach. So far I have not come across a situation where it does not work, but the number of platforms I have to play with is quite limited.